# python and appending to JSON file

Tags: python, json

I have a tabbed window that I ask users to input some data, then press a button that updates both a list view and appends the new data to the end of a JSON file, but I can't seem to figure out how to append the data within the square [ ] brackets to make it valid JSON, so what I want is:

```
[
    {
        "store": "My Store",
        "address": "123 Anywhere Calgary, Ab",
        "category": "Grocery",
        "item": "Ground Coffee",
        "qty": "1",
        "price": "10.99",
        "GST": false,
        "PST": false,
        "EHC": "0.",
        "deposit": "0.",
        "other": "0."
    },
    {
        "store": "My Store",
        "address": "123 Anywhere Calgary, Ab",
        "category": "Grocery",
        "item": "Flour, All Purp",
        "qty": "1",
        "price": "9.99",
        "GST": false,
        "PST": false,
        "EHC": "0.",
        "deposit": "0.",
        "other": "0."
    },
    {   
        "store": "My Store",
        "address": "123 Anywhere Calgary, Ab",
        "category": "Grocery",
        "item": "Taco Shells",
        "qty": "1",
        "price": "4.59",
        "GST": false,
        "PST": false,
        "EHC": "0.",
        "deposit": "0.",
        "other": "0."
    },
    {
        "store": "My Store",
        "address": "123 Anywhere Calgary, Ab",
        "category": "Grocery",
        "item": "BBQ Sauce",
        "qty": "1",
        "price": "3.79",
        "GST": false,
        "PST": false,
        "EHC": "0.",
        "deposit": "0.",
        "other": "0."
    },
    {
        "store": "My Store",
        "address": "123 Anywhere Calgary, Ab",
        "category": "Grocery",
        "item": "Ritz Bits",
        "qty": "1",
        "price": "3.49",
        "GST": false,
        "PST": false,
        "EHC": "0.",
        "deposit": "0.",
        "other": "0."
    }
]
```

Which validates as correct JSON format, but what I get when appending to the file is:

```
[
    {
        "store": "My Store",
        "address": "123 Anywhere Calgary, Ab",
        "category": "Grocery",
        "item": "Ground Coffee",
        "qty": "1",
        "price": "10.99",
        "GST": false,
        "PST": false,
        "EHC": "0.",
        "deposit": "0.",
        "other": "0."
    }
]
[
    {
        "store": "My Store",
        "address": "123 Anywhere Calgary, Ab",
        "category": "Grocery",
        "item": "Flour, All Purp",
        "qty": "1",
        "price": "9.99",
        "GST": false,
        "PST": false,
        "EHC": "0.",
        "deposit": "0.",
        "other": "0."
    }
]
```

Which because of the [ ] brackets is enclosing each appended item, it is no longer valid JSON. So how can I append the items between the [ and ] in order to keep the JSON valid? Is there a way to maybe append the items, then go to the beginning of the file and insert the [, then move to the end of the file and append ]?

The problem is, the user can add groceries to the JSON file anytime they want as I am technically using the JSON as a 'database'. When the user runs the program, I want to be able to re-read in the JSON data and populate the list control with the previous entries.

Or should I look at a different method of storing the data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open("my_file.json","rb") as f:
    existing = json.load(f)
existing.append(item)
with open("my_file.json","wb") as f:
    json.dump(existing,f)
```

or better yet abstract it out

```
class JSONList(object):
     def __init__(self,fname):
        self.fname = fname
        self.items = []
        self.load()


     def save():
        with open(self.fname,"wb") as f:
            json.dump(self.items,f)

     def load(self):
        try:
            self.items = json.load(open(self.fname,"rb"))
        except: # bad form empty except... but whatever
            self.items = []

     def append(self,new_item,save=True):
        self.items.append(new_item)
        if save:
           self.save()
```

Comment: Also better yet, include an intermediary step to back up the current version of the file and restore it in case the write operation fails. Plus you could do this by inheriting `list` instead of `object`, which would give you more useful collection methods in addition to not having to track the items themselves (just use `super().append(...)`).

Comment: sure plenty of truth to all that ... inheriting from builtins like list and str can get wonky sometimes... so i was trying to keep it sort of minimal